# CakePHP : 1054 Unknown column 'User.id' in 'field list'

Tags: cakephp

I am learning CakePHP. There, I am stuck with following problem:

I have a table called **comments** with fields comment_id, comment_title, comment_text, comment_date & user_id.
Also I have my **users** table with fields user_id, user_name, user_email, created_date.

Then in my **User** model I am trying to create a hasMany relationship like :

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
    'className' => 'Comment',
    'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
    ), );
```

But this giving me an error

> 1054 Unknown column 'User.id' in 'field list'

I know this is because I don't have an ***id*** column in my users table instead I have ***user_id***

Now, my question is : is there a way to fix this without renaming the *user_id* field of user table? As this will require change in every existing code where I have used *user_id* ?

Comment: Why are you not simply following the conventions and name the primary keys "id" in your tables? This will save you a good amount of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set in your **User** model:

```
public $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

If you need create some relationship and models, controller, views.. You can use **Bake** shell, see: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/code-generation-with-bake.html

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this kind of errors use foreign key constraints in database.
Cakephp automatically add associations between tables.

Answer (score -1):

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className' => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => array('Comment.user_id' => 'User.user_id'),
        'dependent' => true
    )
);
```

Comment: Hey @vikram, it's always better if you can offer some commentary about what is causing the OPs problem and what exactly your solution does to solve that.